# What must I do to get FluentValidation to display my custom messages?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, fluentvalidation

Right now, it is just displaying a generic

> 'Initials' should not be empty.

message for the following rule:

```
context.RulesFor(p => p.Initials).Required(p => p.Message("Initials are frikking required.")).Length(0, 8);
```

The initials propety is declared in a rather large model of type `ApplicantProfileModel : MappedViewModel<ApplicantProfile>` as just plain `public string Initials { get; set; }`, without even a display name attribute, yet I have the same problem even when I add a display name.

I have no `Required` attributes left in the view models.

The controller action code is:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var applicant = _applicantService.BuildApplicantProfile();
    var model = new ApplicantProfileModel();
    model.MapFromEntity(applicant);
    return View(model);
}
```

This is my standard code for my last umpteen projects, and everything works except the FluentValidation custom messages. Their validations wok fine.

The view is:

```
<li class="form-line">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Initials)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Initials)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Initials)
</li>
```

I tried `TextBoxFor` as well, but no difference.

Comment: Your code seems fine. What's the type of the `Initials` property? Could you show a full example (including model, view and controller) allowing to reproduce the problem you are describing here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you left a `[Required]` DataAnnotation attribute on the property? I've found that those get displayed instead of my custom validation rules if they've been left on.

EDIT: This is how I've set the validators up in the past - it may also be that they're not firing because you're doing a `HttpGet` rather than a `HttpPost` and you need to manually call Validate?

```
public class ApplicantProfileModelValidator : AbstractValidator<ApplicantProfileModel>
{
    public ApplicantProfileModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(r => r.Initials)
            .NotEmpty()
            .WithMessage("Initials are frikking required.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, not a one `Required` anywhere in that model. It is the first model I'm tying Fluent on.

Comment: Could you show the full code the for validator? It could be the way that you set that up

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had mixed up two different, but very similar valiation libraries. I initially started with [ASP.NET MVC fluent validation framework](http://fluentmvc.codeplex.com/documentation), or known on NuGet as **FluentMVC**. This requires your model to implement a method called `InitializeModel(ModelContext<TModel> context)`, in which you add rules for various properties, e.g.

```
context.RulesFor(p => p.Id).Required(p => p.Message("Id is missing. Message may have been tampered with.").StopOnFail());
```

The validation engine somehow calls this method on all models, because although instructed to implement an `IModelInitializer<TModel>` interface on your validated models, I am not. This is not to say the rules are being registered, but some part of this library is active and interfeing with the library I am trying to use, **[FluentValidation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/),** known on NuGet as FluentValidation, FluentValidation.MVC3 and FluentValidation.MVC4.

Having rmoved the `InitializeModel` mehod from my model, things seem to be working. My rude test messages for validation now show, so they won't sneak past testing and the release manager.